# Formatting Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, formatting

I have an object like this :

```
[{name:'abcd', data:[1,2,3,4,5,6]},{name:'cdef', data:[7,8,9,10,11,12]}]
```

and I would like to format it like this :

```
[{abcd:1, cdef:7},{abcd:2, cdef:8}, {abcd:3, cdef:9}, ... ]
```

help please !

Comment: What are your attempts so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and `forEach()` methods.

```js
var data = [{name:'abcd', data:[1,2,3,4,5,6]},{name:'cdef', data:[7,8,9,10,11,12]}]

var result = data.reduce(function(r, {name, data}) {
  data.forEach((e, i) => {
    if(!r[i]) r[i] = {[name]: e};
    else r[i][name] = e;
  })
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```